# Create A circle using js or Css and resize it based on width of Div

Tags: jquery, css, canvas, clip

i was trying to make a circle that is divided on few parts and it has hover region on numbers 1,2,3.But here i have couple of problems when i make this circle using clip-path etc it does not support many browser.Is this possible to make this circle using css or Canvas / Css clipping and resize it based on div height and width?? That can be compatible to all modern browsers?

[image]

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: I have tried this but you can't write on shapes using this techniques

Comment: I would use SVG for this kind of task

Comment: I have also tried "SVG" circle for this task, 
https://jsfiddle.net/p5a8up2L/1/

Its is not compatible with cross browsers. click region not working for webkit browsers.